# Websocket backend client connection stops receiving stream updates after a while

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using nodejs's [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) to get a stream of data from a remote websocket server. After a while, I simply stop receiving data from the remote server. There are no errors, or close events. The data simply stops arriving.

What's interesting is that the time before I stop receiving data varies with the specs of the host system.

For instance, on my laptop, which is a 4-core i7 with 16GB memory, it can run overnight (about 8-9 hours) before I stop receiving data. On a small AWS EC2 server, I stop receiving data within 10 minutes.

If I force a reconnect to the remote server, the data starts coming in and will stop receiving after a while again. My current workaround to the issue is to simply reconnect to the remote server every 10 minutes.

I initially thought this was a bug with the remote server I was connecting to, so I switched my data provider. But I am still seeing the issue.

The memory, cpu and file descriptor usage of the nodejs process is nominal. The strace doesn't show anything interesting. I need some ideas on how I can debug this.

Please be reminded that I'm not connecting to the websocket server from the browser, I'm connecting to it from a nodejs script.

Comment: Can you try creating the socket like this `var io = require('socket.io')(http, {'pingTimeout': 7000}, 'pingInterval': 3000);` ?

Comment: "There are no errors, or close events" Are you checking that both on server and client side? Also try to check the event "attemp" to see if the server or the client is attempting to reconnect with no success but no error is being registered

Comment: @TarunLalwani - that didn't help. I ran with that ping setting a couple of times today, and had the same issue.

Comment: @LuisPinto - The server doesn't belong to me. I'm connecting to third-party servers.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Try adding the option ``'upgrade': false`` in the socket connection options. Also, why are you using socket.io-client if you are using this server side?

Comment: @HyderA, possible to share which service it is or that is a confidential information?

Comment: Are you able to monitor the available / free memory on the sending and receiving servers? If so, do you see the available / free memory shrink while the socket data transmission is processing?

Comment: @HRK44 - Tried `upgrade: false`. That didn't false. While this is on the server-side, the websocket connection is a client to a remote server.

Comment: @TarunLalwani - I tested with both Coinigy and Cryptocompare

Comment: @JohnH I only have control over the receiving server. The sending server is third-party. The memory expands and shrinks, but that could very well be because of the data being processed.

Comment: That indicates me that this is some kind of memory leak or some unset listeners. Have you tried to isolate the problem to the particular code you are using for the websocket connection? It might be even be a side-effect of some other piece of code.

Might be some kind of buffer becoming full then stops receiving data because it's not flushed.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `DEBUG` environment variable to `'*'`, you will be able to see a lot more information that is happening under the hood (things like ping/pong, disconnects, reconnects, events, etc). This should help narrow down where the issue lies. If that shows too much information, you could also try setting the `DEBUG` environment variable to `'socket*,engine*'`.

Comment: While this is helpful, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Apologies if this was posted wrong. The question was asking for ways to debug this, so I would still think this is more of an answer than just a comment, but either way, just trying to help :]

Comment: @EvanLucas Yes, I consider this an answer. I don't think anyone can solve an issue like this without debugging the server. Let me try the DEBUG flag, can't believe I didn't think of this.

Comment: @EvanLucas This didn't help, no relevant info showed up when the data stopped arriving.